# Flutter Splash Screens The Right Way?

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I am trying to build a basic splash screen in flutter. I have tried various packages from pub such as `flutter_splash`, `splashscreen` etc. They do show up but with customization limitations such as `text below logo` but the main problem is that, it shows the default white screen first, then a black screen before my splash screen.

I have seen the flutter docs on adding your own assets in `xml files` but nothing seems to be happening.

Here's my code:
1. `launch_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo.png" />
</item>
```

the logo has been added to the various mipmap density folders but doesn't show either. The `styles.xml` is same since I want the white background.

Using `splashscreen` library, here's the code:

```
import 'package:eme_clone/utils/constants.dart';
```

import 'package:eme_clone/utils/router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() =>
runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'EME Water App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: homeRoute,
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
    )
);
```

router.dart file

```
import 'package:eme_clone/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:eme_clone/screens/splash.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eme_clone/utils/constants.dart';

class Router {

 static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings){
   switch (settings.name){
     case splashRoute:
       return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> Splash());
     case homeRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Home());
      break;
    }
  }

 }
```

and the `constants.dart` file

```
  /**
  *  Routes
  * */

 const String splashRoute = '/splash';
 const String homeRoute = '/';
```

Any help to get rid of the black screen or explanation and how to solve my above problem will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your manifest file? May be you didn't add there.

Answer (score 0):

In your main.dart, create a SplashScreen class and then in your

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: "default"
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

add initState in your SplashScreen class then create a future function whatever you want to do,

```
 Future _dohere()async{
     if(true){
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomePage()))
    }else{
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> LoginPage()))
    }
}

@override
void initState(){
 super.initState();
 _dohere();
}
```

Comment: I used a timer to push to some other widget using duration prop. What is the boolean being evaluated here? I don't see it but I got the logic, need that to complete my train of thoughts. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using Bloc pattern for state management and this works fine: Base on the Authentication status, we return the relevant screen:

In the `main.dart`, use a BlocBuilder `AuthenticationBloc` (comes from the dependency [`flutter_bloc`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or use `StreamBuilder` yourself) as the followings:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {

  App({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
              return LoginPage();
            }

            if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
              return LoadingIndicator();
            }

            if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
              return HomePage();
            }

            return SplashPage(); ///when state is AuthenticationUninitialized
          },
        ),
      );
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used the bloc pattern yet but will take this under advisement. The main issue here is the black screen after the native splash in this order => native splash => black screen => my_splash => some widget view.